# Dart version is still same even after updating Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, version, upgrade

I need the latest version of the dart to use a package in android studio. So I tried to update flutter and checked the dart version. The version got updated as shown below.
But the `dart --version` still shows the old version being used by the app

> flutter --version
>
> Flutter 2.3.0-0.1.pre • channel dev •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>
> Framework • revision d72bfb8d07 (7 days ago) • 2021-04-26 06:05:55
> -0700
>
> Engine • revision de6e1adf97
>
> Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-18.0.dev)
>
> dart --version
>
> Dart SDK version: 2.10.5 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

*Update* : *I just changed the directory to sudo directory and it solves*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGg0J.png)

Comment: Run `which dart`.  What does it say?  You have a separate version of the Dart SDK installed somewhere with its copy of the `dart` binary earlier in your `PATH`.

Comment: 'which dart' gives /usr/bin/dart and
'which flutter' gives /snap/bin/flutter

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer this for you. But if this help others I will post a solution which helped me fix it.

- When you type `which dart` it showed a diff location than your
  flutter sdks dart. So go to that dart location(in your case
  **/usr/bin/dart**) and rename the file with name dart to some other name.
- Now go to the terminal and check for `which dart` and you should be seeing the updated dart now.

I hope this works as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem also while building [hiideemedia](https://hiideemedia.com) app but later I noticed I have two flutter version on my system. I kept the flutter in /users/flutter and delete the second one. Also change the path in android studio. This might be helpful as it help me solves it.

Comment: The link to your product doesn't seem at all necessary for this answer, and linking to it unnecessarily makes it look a lot like you're spamming. I would suggest removing the link unless it's strictly necessary for this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Dart version compatibility depends on your `pubspec.yaml`. If you want to force 2.12.0 you can declare:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because xylophone requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because xylophone requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: @BikeshMaharjan What's your current pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: the pubspec,yaml file has environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: @BikeshMaharjan So what's your issue? As I told you, when you want to have 2.12.0 you have to change it to  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0".

Comment: when I change the pubspec.yaml file like you said and run 'pub get' on terminal I get error : The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5. Because xylophone requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because xylophone requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed

Comment: @BikeshMaharjan what happens when you change the version and remove xylophone  for that step?